# Performance evaluation in terms of channel MSE and BER

Tags: signal-detection, fading-channel

The first figure on the left (in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8304692/)) provides the channel NMSE performance and the the second figure from left provides detector's BER performance.

I am curious, when the channel MSE overlapped in the first figure, why there is a difference between the BER performance.

I think, that there should be no difference, Moreover, even if there is a gap between MSE the use of quantizer of quantizer can bridge the gap in BER performance.

Thanks

Comment: its a bit tough to answer this without access to the paper. Maybe you can share the figure and the system model?

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé please visit this link for detailed information. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1banEbmRGMHtInarFvwE-gZttQRjZ7bIc).

The question is about the figure 2b and 2c in this paper. THe model under consideration is a linear system given by eq. 6

Comment: the link is not accessible, as it asks me for permission

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé please, use this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1banEbmRGMHtInarFvwE-gZttQRjZ7bIc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

From the simulation section of the paper:

> The SER for each Monte Carlo simulation is calculated as follows: **only
>   when the activity state and the transmitted symbol are both detected
>   correctly** for a certain user, the corresponding user’s information is
>   considered to be correct, and all symbols transmitted by the user
>   whose activity state is mistakenly detected are considered to be
>   incorrect. To provide a benchmark for performance comparison, we
>   consider **the oracle LS by assuming the actual active user support set
>   known at the BS**.

---

> However, the SER performance gap of the proposed joint CE and MUD
>   framework and the oracle LS always remains. This is mainly due to the
>   CS-based sparse signal reconstruction algorithm with non-orthogonal
>   training matrix suffers significantly, **so that the data detection
>   error is the main cost of user activity detection**.

The non-oracle receiver has to figure out who is transmitting and hence can do additional errors. The oracle knows this information already. That's why you have the difference in the SER.

Comment: I think that the channel MSE also follows the same concept as BER. so if the MSE is converging, BER should converge too as MSE is also a function of the active users.